# My application for Samsung Wave not working

Tags: c++, bada

My application in working fine in Samsung BADA simulator but not working in device. My application is for S8500, available for download https://sourceforge.net/projects/wavechm/ with source code. I don't know what to do now?

---

please see the video of application how it is behaving. I have no idea what to do next. It is open source project and I do lot of hardwork and getting no result.

http://developer.bada.com/badaforum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=ide-sdk&messageId=24162&frm=1

Comment: Define: "not working".  What do you expect?  What does it do?

Comment: It is a chm reader for samsung wave mobile. I don't have wave s8500 mobile so i can;t check how and why my application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this app on phone 
`6,0,0,1,2011-05-13,02:10:27.578,1|5
Transfer completed.
The "COM5" port is closed.
The "COM5" port is open.
Command message: [1600:1601]EnableDiagWrite
Command message: [1600:1601]TerminateProcessEx feu46uenau 0
Command message: [1600:1601]AppPkgInstall /Osp/Applications/feu46uenau
Command message: [0:2]MID_PROCESSMGR,0xFF
3,0,0,1,2011-05-13,02:10:29.421,00004|10:47:85|PHONESTATUS:04> app installed, errType=0
Installation completed.
2,0,0,1,2011-05-13,02:10:29.421,Info, Installation completed.
The "COM5" port is closed.
6,0,0,1,2011-05-13,02:10:31.953,2|1|5
2,0,0,1,2011-05-13,02:10:37.406,0072.217,EXCEPTION,P28,T00,A119,Osp::Ui::Controls::Popup::Show (689) > [E_SYSTEM] Unable to show itself.
The "COM6" port is closed.`
It is short log. App crashed and broke os too. (didn't stop in IDE)

Let me know which details you need. I try to help.

Comment: thanks for nice information. from last line of log it looks like there is some exception in startup popup window. I will check this. (currently I m outside. I will able to check this within 2-3 days)